# A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'. > Could not read script - app_plugin_loader.gradle doesnt exist

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

So I am facing the problem above, when I run --info ill get these insights:

```
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
```

> Could not read script 'C:...\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle' as it does not exist.

So I get that app_plugin_loader.gradle doesnt exist. But how do I fix that?

I already tried running `npm install react-native-unimodules`

That didnt work out.

It says that the error is thrown here in my settings.gradle:

```
    include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

In the last line:

```
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

How can I fix this?